# Creating an Browser like back button in Webview android

Tags: android

I have an back button(Image Button) on the webview. I want to make this back button work like browser back button.
Whenever the user clicks on the back button it should move to the previous web page.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an `OnClickListener` for that `ImageButton` and inside `onClick()` write something like this:

```
if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
     mWebView.goBack();
}else{
     finish();
}
```

See [WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) guide from Android

Answer (score 1):

Use One image button

create the onClick event of that button

insite the onClick Button you have to write

webview.goBack();

this code will work as back button of browser.